# Conditional highlightColor on MaterialButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a quiz with multiple buttons. When the user presses the button for the right answer I want the button to have a highlightColor of green. If its the wrong button then the highlightColor is red. The issue I have is when I click a button the right highlightColor will show but you also get a glimpse of the wrong color. If I use the splashColor instead then you only see the right color which is good but the effect is not the same.

Here is a simplified version of the code with just one button but with the same issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {

    bool    _winner = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                        Text(
                            'Press the button:',
                        ),

                        MaterialButton(
                            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                            height: 60.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[800],
                            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                            //splashColor: _winner ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                            highlightColor: _winner ? Colors.green : Colors.red,

                            onPressed: () {

                                setState(() {
                                });
                                _winner ? _winner=false : _winner=true;

                            }
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing here with the `highlight` fade animation that it last 200 milliseconds and the `setState` is called before the animation is over, thats why you get glimpse of the other color.

One solution is to `setState` after 200 milliseconds delay.

```
onPressed: () {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                setState(() {});
                _winner ? _winner = false : _winner = true;
              });
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to use GestureDetector with onTap event

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  bool _winner = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('widget.title'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Press the button:',
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (_) {
                setState(() {});
                _winner ? _winner = false : _winner = true;
              },
              child: ColorButton(
                isWinner: _winner,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.isWinner,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isWinner;

  @override
  _ColorButtonState createState() => _ColorButtonState();
}

class _ColorButtonState extends State<ColorButton> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        height: 60.0,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        color: isPressed
            ? widget.isWinner ? Colors.green : Colors.red
            : Colors.grey[800],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```